# How can i be notified that the user is logging out?

Tags: macos

I am writing a user agent that needs to perform some cleanup when the user logs out of OS X.  The agent is NOT receiving a SIGINT (neither SIGTERM, and neither SIGKILL) signal.  Because of this, the agent process is remaining as a "ghost" process running on the Mac, and it will no longer respond to any attempts I do to kill it.  I need to be notified that the user is logging out and then I can handle the shut-down of the Agent gracefully.

I know about the CFNotificationCenter, but I could not find any example on how to use it for logout.  Actually I did not find a list describing the possible notifications (at least the standard ones) that I can observe using the CFNotificationCenter.  Can anyone help me please ?

Regards
Alan

Comment: What about SIGHUP - the original signal sent on 'hang-up' (as of a telephone modem connection hanging up)?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, that worked.

NSD, yes I have a plist in /Library/LaunchAgents/ to launch my agent automatically when the user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has [a document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1133/_index.html) describing how this is done.  Essentially, you use the `SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser` to check the currently signed in user.  If this is *loginwindow*, you know that no user is logged in.  You can then register for a notification whenever the current GUI console user changes.